# How does one know if a normal vector is between two angles?

Tags: c#, math

I have a Max Angle and a Min Angle, and also a unit vector pointing in some direction (2D).

How do I find out if this normal vector is between the two angles?

Comment: It *always* is, until you come up with a better definition of "between".

Comment: there is a big difference between a *normal* vector and a *unit* vector. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the angle from the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation) (this is easy in 2d) and then compare to your angle range.

Comment: -1: The dot product is a product between two vectors. So, dot product with what? Moreover, the dot product gives you the *cosine* of the angle, so you'd have to do an `arccos()` of the dot product, or a `cos()` on both `MaxAngle` and `MinAngle` to be able to compare them. This solution is also not four-quadrant, and thus has ambiguities.

Comment: Take the dot product with the axis that defines the 0 angle. And yes `arccos()` would be necessary, I was providing the asker with the knowledge to complete the process, not the entire process.

Comment: Your answer is simply 1) incomplete, and 2) too complicated for the problem at hand. Moreover, it is something that will certainly lead to more problems in the nearby future, because of the phase ambiguities inherent to arccos(). Granted, your method is better extensible to 3D, and the OP should sure read up on dot products. Nevertheless, I'll only remove my -1 if you give a *complete* answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know c#, but I know math:

Suppose the vector's coordinates are `(x,y)`, and it is a unit vector, so `|(x,y)| = 1`. 
The angle `a` between the positive `x`-axis and the vector is

```
a = atan2(y,x)
```

where `atan2` is the four-quadrant arctangent. You can then check if this angle is between your max and min angles (provided they are also defined with respect to the positive `x`-axis).

Note that `a` is in radians; if your angles are given in degrees, you should first compute

```
a = a*180/pi;
```

where `pi = 3.1415.....` of course.

Does this help at all?